# Table of Contents Formatting Problem, Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, tableofcontents

I am trying to achieve the TOC formatting depicted in this screenshot. Is there a way to do it neatly, right aligned, using the native Microsoft Word TOC tools? I have to use the native Microsoft tools as it is a colossal document that someone else set up, which I now need to make presentable. This is the last step in the process before it'll be ready for publishing.

[TOC problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygn1M.png)

Comment: Please ask this question in a venue that supports end-user topics, such as Super User. Non-programming questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might want to take a moment to review the site's guidelins in the [help].

Comment: See: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/18118-how-align-table-figures-contents.html#post52345

Comment: Cheers Ciny I will move my question over to Super User, thanks for the advice. 

And @macropod thank you very much, that may very well be exactly what I need. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific formatting that you are trying to achieve is not possible using the native Word TOC tools. This is because the TOC exists as a single field in the document and the TOC entries exist only within that field. Each entry can therefore only occupy a single paragraph.

Whilst you can edit the tab stops in the TOC paragraph styles to create more space for the heading number this will not cause the number to wrap if it is too long. What you are trying to achieve would only be possible in a table cell.

A possible solution may be to finalize the document, generate the TOC, unlink the TOC field to leave the text and create a table from the text.